# Possibility of building a landmass connecting Asia and America in the future

Tags: technology, climate, geography, geopolitics

I am thinking of a scenario in which a climatic change and rising sea levels (whether true or not IRL) is threatening the Earth and I have learned that changes in sea levels might be caused by melting glaciers, I propose an idea in which countries around Beringia (the region) begin to create a large enough landmass connecting between Asia and America (creating the Bering land bridge) assuming it would cool up the climate in the Arctic. I am asking if this scenario set around 2040-2060 might be possible if someone had to propose the idea. Adding that in this scenario, Russia collapses and new countries located next to Alaska decide to help the US in the process.

The size of the project is rather large, ending up to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Question: Why would a Bearing strait land bridge cool the climate in the Arctic?

Comment: @TheDemonLord Now that you ask I feel stupid about that since I didn't really check my sources, I was thinking that cold might accumulate within the Arctic and block hot air from the pacific ocean from entering the Arctic. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Don't feel stupid - afterall, it's your story. If your intent though is to block hot air/water from traversing from the Pacific into the Arctic, you are gonna need a lot more than just a land bridge - and I don't think whatever you need is possible with our current level of tech or with 'future necessity driven tech'. Perhaps adjust your time period or think outside the box - good luck with your writing.

Comment: *"New countries located next to Alaska decide to help the US in the process":* If you mean the [Chukotka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukotka_Autonomous_Okrug)., that's basically empty land, with a population density about 150 times lower than Niger, which is a country in the *Sahara*.

Comment: How big do you want this to be? In other words, a couple miles wide, or are you looking to recreate Beringia as it was thousands of years ago?

Comment: @elemtilas Basically this size: https://preview.redd.it/q76kmtfjg7281.png?auto=webp&s=f3ed464f38aa43dfc036823644bd67a4d1078c23

Comment: @Bangerblade, it isn't the hot air from the pacific that is warming the Arctic, it is the water moving up. Water moves a lot more heat and drives the hot air movements. Blocking the ocean current from the pacific might have the impact you want. But moving that much dirt would be a massive effort.

Comment: Seems like an impossible project with any real world technology. I mean if you want to build something like this why not just build a bridge or something?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a clear question here, you might want to clarify that.

Looking at the feasibility of your project, I'd say your timeline is way off.

First, the existing land reclamation/building projects we have in the Netherlands, Japan or Chinese islands are at least two orders of magnitude smaller, and took years (for the small ones) or decades (for the larger). A project the size you show would take a century or two with near-future technology.

The Bering Strait is only around 90m deep, but your project is larger than the Strait, and even if we assumed 90m throughout, the sheer amount of landmass to move is considerable. You can draw your continent in a GIS software and get its surface area calculated.

Second, if Russia collapses within the next few years, it'll be a decade at least of turmoil, given past experiences, and another two or three before it could undertake such a mega-project.